# zend db error on switching tables Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to __construct() must be an array, object given, called in

Tags: php, zend-framework, centos, zend-db, zend-db-table

In my application I have set up the db connection. Now i want to switch tables and i keep getting following error

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application_Model_PgeSeismicFile::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in /opt/eposdatatransfer/application/models/PgeSeismicFileMapper.php on line 58 and defined in /opt/eposdatatransfer/application/models/PgeSeismicFile.php on line 10
```

I have two models for the two tables. i get error when I try to access the second table. Accessing and setting the 1st table is fine and i do it the same way. Here is how I am switching the tables.

```
private $_dbTable = null;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable, $path = false)
    {
        $project = $_REQUEST['username'];

        $filename = $path . "PSDB.db"; //APPLICATION_PATH . "/data/db/".$project."/PSDB.db";

        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            //$this->_redirect('/');
            // need to redirect and pass eror message for user
            throw new Exception("File does not exist");
        }

        try{
            //exit("3");
            $dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory("pdo_sqlite", array("dbname"=> $filename));
        }catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
            // perhaps a failed login credential, or perhaps the RDBMS is not running
            var_dump($e);
            exit("1");

        } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
            // perhaps factory() failed to load the specified Adapter class
            var_dump($e);
            exit("2");
        }

        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            print_r($dbAdapter);
            $dbTable = new $dbTable($dbAdapter);
            $dbTableRowset = $dbTable->find(1);
            $user1 = $dbTableRowset->current();
            //var_dump($user1);
            //exit("hello");
            //$row = $user1->findDependentRowset();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        //$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
        //$session->dbAdapter = $this->_dbTable;
        //var_dump($this);
        //exit();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable($path = false)
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
            //$this->setDbTable('Application_Model_PgeSeismicFile',$path);
            $this->dbTable = new Application_Model_PgeSeismicFile($session->dbAdapter);
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }
```

It errors on this line

```
$this->dbTable = new Application_Model_PgeSeismicFile($session->dbAdapter);
```

In my session i am storing:

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory("pdo_sqlite", array("dbname"=> $filename));
```

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand in specific?

Comment: where it needs to pass an array and not an object. The first time I access a table It is passing an object so why is it the second time it does not work? Following is my seismicfile model `public function __construct(array $options = null)
 {
  if (is_array($options)) {
   $this->setOptions($options);
  }
 }`

Comment: Variables are not constants, they can change their value over time.

Comment: I think the error says it all the constructor is not overloaded and needs an array (config) as its first argument. You passed in an Object (Zend_Db_Table)

Comment: I understand now. I have change the parameter to pass: `array("dbname"=> $filename)` where filename points to the sqlite filepath. But what i do nto understand is how comes the first time i load sqlite connection to a table i can pass an object.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db::factory("pdo_sqlite", array("dbname"=> $filename));

Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapter);

$this->dbTable = new Application_Model_PgeSeismicFile;
```